# Deploying Node.js express and MySQL application without using any cloud platform

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, deployment, web-deployment

I have my Nodejs express application running on my local computer with mysql DB. Now, I want to deploy this application to a web server.
My problem is, I haven't done this before , so I thought a quick google will give me clue and lead me somewhere. All I have found is deploying to Amazon, Azure, Heroku, Digital Ocean and so on which provides to the best of my knowledge a cloud service. 
I use domain factory, they are not cloud. I use bit bucket as my source control. How do I deploy my node server on the server of domain factory.?
After some hours of search ; i found some steps but I have tried none seems to work out. 
I found this information,and others but there seems not to be a clear cut guide to do this apart from using a cloud service to push your project them. 
Does anyone have a link or a guide as to how I can host my application 
http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/deploying-nodejs-apps

Answer (score 2):

It is incredibly easy to deploy your node.js express app to Heroku.
Just follow [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction) to understand how to deploy a node.js app to Heroku.

Once you have understood it, you will be able to deploy your app to heroku with a simple "git push heroku master".

You can continue using bitbucket as your git repo for source control. You can simply define spearate git remotes for bitbucket and Heroku.

As for mysql: There are plenty of "MySQL as a Service" solutions out there for Heroku, such as the [cleardb](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cleardb) Heroku add on.

By using the free tier for Heroku and cleardb, you can probably run your app for free on Heroku.